# Django: three models in relation to each other, what is the best way

Tags: django, many-to-many, models, relationship, one-to-one

I have an online shop. there are single items to buy, but there are also some sets which contain some of those single items.
Now i am trying to find the best/usefull solution for these relations. That is what i have so far.

models:

```
class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class WineBox(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    wines = models.ManyToManyField(Wine)

class Product(models.Model):
    wine = models.OneToOneField(Wine, blank=True, null=True)
    winebox = models.OneToOneField(WineBox, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    public = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, but at the end I came up with a very easy solution that fit my needs perfectly. I didn't want to use generic relations, because I have control about all of my models and they make everything complicated, or Cartucho solutions, because I might want to have more Products later. I use Product as a base class and now the models look like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    public = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

class Wine(Product):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class WineBox(Product):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    wines = models.ManyToManyField(Wine)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are both `WineBox` and `Product` necessary? Seems to be a bit redundant. Why not something easier like:

```
class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Product(models.Model):
    wine = models.ForeignKey(Wine)
    winebox = models.ManyToManyField(Wine)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    public = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

That still looks redundant, I'd prefer to remove the `wine` field from `Product` and leave just:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    wines = models.ManyToManyField(Wine)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    public = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good point! My first idea was to add additional information to WineBox, like a package shot or a different title. (Sorry I wasn't so specific in my question.) But maybe it's worth adding this to the Product class instead of having an additional Model.

Comment: @horndash My best advice is keep your data model simple and don't over-design. Cheers!

Comment: I would look into generic relationships for this problem: Let's say you want to have multiple types of products, at the moment the `Product` can only have `Wine`s as "content". Check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1